# Who did we hear in Bran's vision in S06E06?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the beginning sequence of *Game of Thrones* S06E06 we see Bran's visions, and in them the Mad King cries "burn them all!" many times. But when Myra stops and touches Bran's face, during his vision of him falling from the tower, we hear somebody calmly say "burn them", immediately followed by the Mad King's shout. Can somebody recognise the voice?

[Here's](http://jig-san.me/heap/sound/bt.mp3) that sound fragment.

First I thought it was Jaime, but I rewatched moments when he repeated the Mad King's words previously in the series, and this doesn't sound like those.

Comment: After just watching this episode I'm pretty sure it's the Mad King

Comment: Maybe it bran himself 'whispering' to the mad king too "burn the others" ... and thats what sent him mad ..... jut like we saw in s6e5 with hodor hearing the whispers of hold the door? just a maybe tho

Comment: @BigTallJosh Kinda different voice, isn't it? I inserted a link to the sound, first phrase and second in the audio, are those said by the same person?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it *wasn't* Aerys II. The only other person who has alluded "burn them all" was Cersei (and that doesn't sound much like her tbh).

Comment: @Mooz I'm not convinced either. If somebody with good ear could confirm it's the same man speaking, that'd be nice.

Comment: Perhaps it could be the voice inside the Mad Kings head firstly as that sounds more demanding and calm. The second time it sounds a little more.. mad as if the king is actually saying what the voices are telling him to do. I don't think it's beyond reasonable doubt given we know he was crazy.

Comment: Just a guess but could it be related to R'hllor, the Lord of Light? I'm not sure but I think the same phrase might have been used when Stannis burned a bunch of people accused of being heretics in Season 1.

Comment: Sounds like a Northerner... Possibly Jon Snow or Joer Mormont...

Comment: @ventsyv Not everything fire-related has something to do with R'hllor.

Answer (score 1):

What if The three eyed raven drove the Mad King mad and caused the rebellion. In knowing through experience that it is impossible to converse anything but imperceivable whispers he tries to train Bran to not make the same mistakes he had.

Also Brynden 'three eyed raven, ex lord crow' Rivers being a legitimized targaryen, would explain why he spent so long with his nephew, the mad king, in the first place. Unintentionally driving him mad in the process.
This further helps understand why he won't let Bran stay where he loves too long, because from his experience, it doesn't turn out well.

Comment: Interesting theory, does the voice in this clip sound like Max von Sydow?